# Open a Serial Terminal session with putty 0.63 in Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit

Tags: windows, serial-port, putty

I want to Start a Serial PuTTy session to a serial port COM3, so I open a Serial putty session with the same characteristics of the USB Serial Port, then I click **Open** but nothing happens , there is no way even in Device properties I can read **"This device is working properly."** and the driver has been installed properly, and I have no problems at all On Mac OS `screen /dev/tty.usbserial-XXXXX`

The Driver installed (http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) :
Windows* / 2.12.04 / x64 (64-bit) :
CDM v2.12.04 WHQL Certified\dpinst-amd64

[image]

Comment: just a question: which kind of device you connected to COM3 ?

Comment: TD 1208 Evaluation Board